# Why array could store key-value pair behavior as object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

We usually use an object to store key-value pairs like

```js
var objs = {};
objs['ios'] = 123
objs['android'] = 239
console.log(objs['ios']); // output 123
```

However, we find array could do the same behavior as an object

```
var arr1 = [];
arr1['ios'] = 123
arr1['android'] = 239
console.log(arr1['ios']);  // output 123

arr1['ios'] = 897
console.log(arr1['ios']);   // output 897
```

Is there any reason behind it?

Comment: Becase in JavaScript, arrays are objects (a specialised form of objects I should say).

Comment: console.log(typeof arr1); // Object

Answer (score 3):

If you go to [Mozilla documentation for Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) the first line you will find is this

> The JavaScript Array class is a global object that is used in the
>   construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects

There is no datatype **Array** in javascript because **Array is nothing but are list-like objects** whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations.

That's the reason in your questions array could do the same behaviour as an object

Comment: But JSON defines an array, that's why when you stringify a JS array with extra properties, you loose the extra properties.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are list-like objects so doing this will not add values to the array but will add properties to the array. You can check length of that array and that will be still 0

```js
var arr1 = [];
arr1['ios'] = 123
arr1['android'] = 239
console.log(arr1['ios']);
console.log(' Length is ' , arr1.length);
// though for ..in is not suggested for array
for (let keys in arr1) {
  console.log(arr1[keys])

}
```

Comment: `but will add properties to the array` that is the OPs question, why?